# Java Regex matching between curly braces

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a log file and get the times and associated function call string
This is stored in the log file as so: {"time" : "2012-09-24T03:08:50", "message" : "Call() started"}

There will be multiple logged time function calls in between other string characters, so hence I am hoping to use regex to go through the file and grab all of these

I would like to grab the entire logged information including the curly brackets

I have tried the following

```
Pattern logEntry = Pattern.compile("{(.*?)}");
Matcher matchPattern = logEntry.matcher(file);
```

and

```
Pattern.compile("{[^{}]*}");
Matcher matchPattern = logEntry.matcher(file);
```

I keep getting illegal repetition errors, please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you need to escape '{' & '}' with a '\'

so: `"{(.*?)}"` becomes: `"\\{(.*?)\\}"`

where you have to escape the '\' with another '\' first

see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for a comprehensive list of characters that need escaping...

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks. I tried to escape and was always getting a compiler error, I was only using one backslash. What is the reason for the double backslash? This is the original error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: because you are escaping the escape character so that it gets fed into the regex compiler for instance: '\n' == new line, '\\' == \ character, and the regex compiler needs to see that since regexs aren't first class citizens in Java (they are in other languages like javascript), they are compiled at runtime, not compile time...

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying at compile time java is thinking its only a string hence"\\" to get "\", and then at runtime it uses that "\" in the regex. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 9):

`Braces` are special regex characters used for repetition groups, therefore you must escape them.

```
Pattern logEntry = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
```

Simple tester:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String x =  "{\"time\" : \"2012-09-24T03:08:50\", \"message\" : \"Call() started\"}";
        Pattern logEntry = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
        Matcher matchPattern = logEntry.matcher(x);

        while(matchPattern.find()) {
            System.out.println(matchPattern.group(1));
        }

    }
```

Gives me:

```
"time" : "2012-09-24T03:08:50", "message" : "Call() started"
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use a positive lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<=\{)([^\}]+)(?=\})
```

- (?<={) Matches everything followed by {
- ([^}]+) Matches any string not containing }
- (?={) Matches everything before {

Comment: This is the only solution that doesn't return curly brackets themself.

Answer (score 0):

{} in regexp have special meaning, so they need to be escaped.

Usually escaping is achieved by preceeding the character to be escaped with a backslash.  In a character class defined with square brackets, you shouldn't need to do this

So something like

```
Pattern.compile("\{[^{}]*\}");
```

Could be nearer to what you want to do

Comment: You must escape the `slash` since it's a Java Special Character

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for non-nested brackets but for expressions like

`(sum(x) * 100) / (sum(y) + sum(z))`

`[a-z]*[\{]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[\}]+` works.