# Unable to replace all characters using .replaceAll method in Java

Tags: java, regex

Unable to replace all characters using .replaceAll method in Java?

I need only https://www.example.co.uk to be outputted to the console window; {}# should be replaced with no character.

**My Method:**

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "#{https://www.example.co.uk}#";

    System.out.println(test.replaceAll("{}", ""));  

}
```

}

**Exception Message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{}
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at BuyAGiftFramework.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Comment: Using the pattern `[{}#]` might do it.

Comment: Also have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586132/java-regex-matching-between-curly-braces

Comment: @hnefatl thanks allot! did the job!